# (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am at the beginners level learning selenium and I started with this simple script to go to google .com and I am hit with an error

My script-

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='\Users\work\Downloads\chromedriver')
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

Here is the error =

```
C:\Users\work\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe "C:/Users/work/Desktop/Python/Selenium/python_selenium_course_material/python_selenium_course_material 2/SELENIUM_SECTION/Browsers_and_Path/lhp.py" 
  File "C:\Users\work\Desktop\Python\Selenium\python_selenium_course_material\python_selenium_course_material 2\SELENIUM_SECTION\Browsers_and_Path\lhp.py", line 3
    driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= 'C\Users\work\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I was expecting  a chrome browser to open up and google.com to load in this browser.
I already have the chrome driver installed.

I tried updating the path with an "r"

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r'C\Users\work\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
```

But this did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double slashes:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= "C:\\Users\\work\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: thank you but that did not work. Here is the error

Traceback (most recent call last):
WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home

Comment: make sure the mentioned path is correct and chromedriver.exe is available in that path.